# Prove by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$F(n)$ for $n \geq 1$ is defined as the sum of all previous values of F

$$F(0) = 1$$

Prove by induction over n that:

> $F(n) = 2^{n-1} \text{ for } n \geq 1$.

These are my steps: $$F(n) = 2^0+2^1+\dots+2^{n-1}= 2^n$$
from here on out i cant seem to find any basecases to fulfill the right side and left side. Left = Right in order to move on. could someone show me the steps to solve this type of induction, so that I can understand it for other types of induction as well.

Comment: You should at least tell us, what your $F(n)$ is. Also $2^0+2^1+\ldots+2^n= 2^{n-1}$ seems wrong. Did you mean  $2^0+2^1+\ldots+2^{n-1}= 2^n$?

Comment: my F(n) is $$2^{n-1}$$

Comment: So you are asked to prove that $2^{n-1}=2^{n-1}$?

Comment: well the question says."F(n) for n ≥ 1 is defined as the sum of all previous values of F" Prove by induction over n that F(n) = $$2^{n-1}$$ for n ≥ 1

Comment: I suppose F(0)=1 is set.

Comment: oh yes exactly, forgot to type that in aswell

Answer (score 1):

Hint (for $n>0$):$$F(n+1)=F(1)+\cdots+F(n-1)+F(n)=F(n)+F(n)=2F(n)$$

Answer (score 0):

Supposed $F(0)=1$ is set and for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you define $F(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} F(i)$. You can prove it with induction:

IS: $n=1: F(1)=F(0)=1=2^0=2^{1-1}$

Suppose you have proven it for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, now try to show this also holds for $n+1$:

$$F(n+1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} F(i) = F(n) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} F(i) = 2 \cdot F(n)$$

Inserting your induction hypothesis you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Given $F(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} F(k)$,

$$F(n) = 2^n$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n - 1}F(k) = 2^n  $$
$$F(n) + \sum_{k=0}^{n - 1}F(k) = F(n) + 2^n $$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n F(k) = 2^n + 2^n $$
$$F(n + 1) = 2^{n + 1} $$